# Merge files into columns

Tags: text

Let's say I have three files with text data:

*file1*

A

B

C

*file2*

1

2

3

*file3*

alpha

beta

gamma

Now I want to get one *FILE* with following format:

A 1 alpha

B 2 beta

C 3 gamma

How can I do it with bash commands?

Answer (score 1):

Very easy command to look into on unix/linux machines is the paste command.

```
paste file1 file2 file3
```